# Create an Excel file in background then email it to the user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an intranet application written in `ASP.NET 4.0` that can generate Excel reports. Some reports can take up to 2 minutes to create.

The problem here is that the user can't continue working while he waits for the report to finish.

What I would like to do is:

1. The user asks the server to generate the report
2. Ther server starts the report and outputs a message saying that the
   report will be emailed to him when ready.
3. While the server is working on the report, the user can continue
   using the intranet
4. When the report is ready, the server saves the Excel file in a
   folder and emails a link to the file to the user

To be clear, I know how to generate an Excel file from .NET code. What I don't know how to do is create it in the background.

How can I do this?

Comment: Search Google for a library to write to Excel files. There are a few out there.

Comment: As I understand the problem is not creating an excel file, it's that it needs to be created in a background task

Comment: That is exactly right

Comment: You might want to check Mr. Hanselman's Blog. It provides a useful list of szenarios, that might solve your problem. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Comment: Keep in mind that Hanselman's blog is providing reccomendations for how to do this *within the web server*. However, doing it on the web server is generally not something you want to do. You'd generally want to do this in a separate application, such as a Windows service or an Azure function. Some of the techniques Hanselman suggested such as Hangfire can be used in Windows services. Or you can wire up communication via Web API or a message queue etc.

Comment: Indeed, doing it on the Server can get you into issues with overtaxed CPU or OOM exceptions because too many unfinished Threads have too much data. You should propably even consider doing some level of caching of common results on the Server side.

Comment: I have edited your question to make it clear that the part you're stuck with is the background processing, not the Excel file generation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to your scenario is to use AJAX call.

1. Create WEBAPI method on your ASP.NET to generate Excel file and email it to user

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public void CreateExcelFile( )
   {
      1.create report
      2.save to disk
      3.call private method to attach the file to email message and send to recipient

   }
   ```
2. In your application web page call that method

   ```
   $.ajax({
   method: "GET",
   url: "./api/yourcontroller/CreateExcelFile",

   })
   .done(function (msg) {
    //do something ???
   }).error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    //catch error if any
   });
   ```

By nature AJAX is async. so your user will be able to continue using your application. If you are looking for a good library for Excel creation I would recommend [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/4.5.0.1-beta) available on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/4.5.0.1-beta) . It is free and very powerful product